# how to fix errors when using SuperLink

Tags: python, ngrok

I am using SuperLink (a tool written in python) to find out how 1 camera is hacked with link.When I created my link, it said that someone visited my link even though I didn't do anything.The tool's screen begins to display information and then reports an error as below.What can I do?

```
[>] IP   : 14.255.152.21

[>] Time : 2021-10-18 | 19:50:18

[>] Saving target GeoIP data...

[#getUserData] ERROR : 'data'
```

[This is the link of Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfFaN.png)

Comment: I believe more than one persons (like you) are using this tool , hence the IP address is being hacked by multiple users and cause such "error" you see. (**Note: hacking can be a serious crime in some countries**)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be about using a tool, not programming it. It _might_ be suitable for https://superuser.com, but only if you can provide more details about the tool and what you're trying to do.

Comment: to Ken Lee's answer: Thanks for the help.I know it's illegal to hack in some countries, I just want to find out how they work so I don't get scammed that way.

Comment: to IMSoP's answer:I'm asking this question because I don't know where to ask. Also, I also plan to create a website with a camera so I want to learn about it.As for the PHP tag, I put it in my post because the tool I'm using uses them. Sorry if it's incorrect.